# Merge Sort not working as it should

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

So there are a bunch of structures with two strings in each. I'm trying to code a merge sort to sort them according to their first strings.

Here's the declaration of structure:

```
struct Voyage {
char city[10];
char time[6];
};
```

They'll be sorted according to the city strings.

Here's the mergeSort function:

```
void mergeSortCities (struct Voyage* voyages, int l, int r){
int m;
if (r > l){
    m = (l+r-1)/2;
    mergeSortCities (voyages, l, m);
    mergeSortCities (voyages, m+1, r);
    mergeCities (voyages, l, m, r);
}
}
```

And merge function:

```
void mergeCities (struct Voyage* voyages, int l, int m, int r){
int i, j, k;
int n1 = m-l+1;
int n2 = r-m;
struct Voyage leftArr[n1], rightArr[n2];

for (i=0;i<n1;i++){
    leftArr[i] = voyages[l+i];
}
for (j=0;j<n2;j++){
    rightArr[j] = voyages[m+1+j];
}

i=0; j=0; k=0;

while (i < n1 && j < n2){
    if (strcmp(leftArr[i].city, rightArr[j].city) <= 0){
        voyages[k] = leftArr[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        voyages[k] = rightArr[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

while (i < n1){
    voyages[k] = leftArr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}
while (j < n2){
    voyages[k] = rightArr[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
}
```

I call the functions with this line in the main function:

```
mergeSortCities (voyages, 0, choice-1);
```

I'll admit that I copy-pasted the algorithm from a website and edited it according to my needs but the results are messed up. They aren't sorted as they were supposed to be. What's wrong with the algorithm? When I enter only two cities, it works. But when I enter 3 strings, like a, b, c and sort them with the functions given above, output is b, c, c.

Comment: `k=0;` --> `k=l;`

Comment: You should have the `mergeSortCities` and the `mergeCities` functions output the values of `l` and `r` each time it's entered. I think you'll find that you have an off-by-one error.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that doesn't fix anything, sir.
JimMischel i'll try that sir. thanks.

Comment: It is incorrect to process an array from `l` to `r` then write back from `0`(not `l`), right?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you were right sir. I thought you wrote 1 and not L there. My bad.

Comment: If you can not distinguish yourself, please never use such a variable name again.